# How Next and Previous link buttons affect on Crawler

Tags: seo, googlebot

I am new to SEO, I had done a research and read several guids, but I am still confused.

A google guid said

> Avoid creating complex webs of navigation links, e.g. linking every
>   page on your site to every other page.

I have an e-commerce website.   We intend to create a page for each issue of a magazine.  issue pages will have Next and Previous link buttons which will move from one issue to another.

Is that a bad idea, Am I violating this rule? or Google is talking about another scenario?

Is that will cause indexing all the 1000 issues? Given that the links are dynamic and I will use URL rewriting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This won't be a problem with Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html). They clearly explain why it is a good thing to do and how to do it properly.

Comment: Actually the link is telling me to NOT use rel=next and rel=previous, because "Google will Send users to the most relevant page/URL—typically the first page of the series"

Actually there is no series.  every article is with a stand alone subject.  I want it all to be indexed.  

As alternative, I will put "alphabitical index page" as the first page, or simply place two links on every issue page.  What do u think?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully control your linkjuice transmition and the landing page from Google with a little website, using this method is not recommanded.

But, if it's for website with more than 1k of unique pages (you can't fully control and influence the webcrawler comportment) you can use this to ease the crawler indexing work and the landing page for users.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination can be a fairly complicated aspect of SEO, especially for ecommerce sites.

Here are a few general tips:

- If you have a "view all" page, you probably should rel="canonical" all your paginated pages to that page. This is acceptable because the content is identical
- If you don't have a "view all" page, but you want Google to treat the first page as the "canonical" or you want to drive all users to the first page, then use the rel=next/prev attributes to "group" together your like pages
- For ecommerce faceted navigation, you should probably use a combination of rel=next/prev and query parameter controls through Google Webmaster Tools

In the June 2012 SMX Advanced conference, there were a few good presentations and live blogging posts that highlights a number of these aspects. More notably, Googler Maile Ohye spoke during that conference ... she's sort of the Queen of Pagination ;)

- http://www.slideshare.net/audette/seo-for-pagination-faceted-navigation-canonicalization-hits-and-misses
- http://outspokenmedia.com/internet-marketing-conferences/pagination-canonicalization-for-the-pros-smx-advanced-2012/
- http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/2012/06/pagination-canonicalization-for-the-pros-smx-advanced/

You might also want to watch this Google video with Maile talking about Pagination http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html

Last thing to note ... Bing doesn't support rel=next/prev at this time: http://searchengineland.com/no-bing-doesnt-support-pagination-attributes-to-consolidate-pages-in-a-series-118694

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly YES Google is talking about another scenario.

The Next and Previous links on the issue pages, used for navigation from one issue to another are different from `<link rel="next" ... >` and `<link rel="previous" ... >` which appear in the `<head> ... </head>` section of html source.

Google will treat webpages with `<link rel="next" ... >` and or `<link rel="previous" ... >` as a series of pages.